# Почему цикл выполняется так много раз? (C#)

Tags: c#, циклы, for

Вот код:

```
using System;

namespace ЧислаФибоначи
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Fibonachi(long a)
        {
            
            long num_1 = 0;
            long num_2 = 1;
            long num_3 = 0;
            for (long i = 0; i < a; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num_3);
                num_3 = num_1 + num_2;
                num_1 = num_2;
                num_2 = num_3;
                
            }
            
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            long a = Console.Read();
            Fibonachi(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Вот вывод(Ввод "3"):

```
0
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144
233
377
610
987
1597
2584
4181
6765
10946
17711
28657
46368
75025
121393
196418
317811
514229
832040
1346269
2178309
3524578
5702887
9227465
14930352
24157817
39088169
63245986
102334155
165580141
267914296
433494437
701408733
1134903170
1836311903
2971215073
4807526976
7778742049
12586269025
20365011074
```

Вопрос: почему цикл выполняется так много раз?

Comment: Что значит много? Он выполняется ровно столько раз, какое число вы введете.

Comment: Читайте документацию по методу [Console.Read](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.read?view=net-5.0). Он выдаёт **код** символа.

Comment: `long a = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`

Answer (score 3):

Метод [Console.Read](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.read?view=net-5.0) выдаёт код символа. [Код символа](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) `'3'` равен `33`.
Вам необходимо прочитать строку целиком и распарсить ее

```
long a = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Либо вычесть код символа `'0'`, если вы уверены что всегда на вход будет приходить один символ

```
char a = Console.Read() - '0';
```